# Searching for React components in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to search for content within* a component without knowing which component it is in? I'm working a new code base and I'm having a hard time identifying which components are which. If I could search for strings I see on the page ("Please click Here" for example) and get components/file results, it would make it easier to navigate the application. Is there a way to do that in VS Code?

Comment: In your browser, you could use the React Developer tools to get a sense of the component heirarchy https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

Comment: @J Seabolt the global search in VS Code would help you to search for text `Ctrl+Shift+f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `shift`-`ctrl`-`F` to bring up the global search. Click on the three horizontal dots (...) to bring up the rest of the dialog. In the "files to include" box, put the file type you want to include (e.g. *.jsx)

[image: Visual Studio Code Search]

Answer (score 6):

You can do Edit, Find in files using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to search through text. Or You can click on search icon shown in the image below indicated as **1**

There is an ellipsis on the dialog where you can include/exclude files, and other options in the search box for matching case/word and using Regex. Check below details.

**2**  - Indicates Refresh

**3**  - Collapse All

**4**  - Clear All

**5**  - Regular Expression

**6**  - Mention include/exclude files

**7**  - Match case/whole word

**8**  - Extend search functionality along with replacing functionality

[image]

Comment: how do you get those key-shaped icons?

Comment: @mankowitz can you be more specific about which you are referring as key-shaped icons?

Comment: @mankowitz you mean **1** the search finder icon on the left corner panel? even your screen-shot includes that icon right, you forgot to mention that option may be